# Testing Polymer with BrowserStack

Tags: polymer, browserstack, web-component-tester

How can I test Polymer elements using web-component-tester over BrowserStack?

I found [this demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/wct-browserstack-demo) but the session times out.

Comment: I tried this command and was able to run the sample test.
1. npm install
2. npm install bower
3. BROWSERSTACK_KEY=<KEY> BROWSERSTACK_USER=<USERNAME> node_modules/.bin/gulp wct:browserstack

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this issue by using this configuration for `wct.conf.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

var ret = {
  'webserver': {
    'pathMappings': []
  }
};

var mapping = {};
var rootPath = (__dirname).split(path.sep).slice(-1)[0];

mapping['/components/' + rootPath  +
'/app/bower_components'] = 'bower_components';

ret.webserver.pathMappings.push(mapping);

/**
 * Adds BrowserStack config
 */
function configBrowserStack(config) {
  var user = process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USER;
  var key = process.env.BROWSERSTACK_ACCESSKEY;
  if (!user || !key) {
    throw new Error('Missing BrowserStack credentials. Did you forget to set BROWSERSTACK_USER and/or BROWSERSTACK_KEY?');
  }

  var url = process.env.BROWSERSTACK_URL
    || 'https://' + user + ':' + key + '@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub';

  var ALL_BROWSERS = require(__dirname + '/default-browserstack-browsers.json');
  var browsers = ALL_BROWSERS.map(function(b) {
    b['browserstack.local'] = process.env.BROWSERSTACK_LOCAL;
    b['browserstack.localidentifier'] = process.env.BROWSERSTACK_LOCAL_IDENTIFIER;
    b['browserstack.build'] = process.env.BROWSERSTACK_BUILD;
    b['url'] = url;
    return b;
  });

  config.activeBrowsers = config.activeBrowsers || [];
  config.activeBrowsers = config.activeBrowsers.concat(browsers);
}

configBrowserStack(ret);

module.exports = ret;
```